# Side pane inside a navigation drawer acivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I want to implement UI behavior like the below image. I'll describe it as follows. I already have an Navigation Drawer activity as my main activity and when user clicks the navigation menu items , different fragments will be loaded into the activity. Let's say I have an list fragment and I need to add filter options to filter the list. when the user taps on a action bar menu item the filter dialog should open as follows. I followed some tutorials and I actually couldn't find anything useful. What will be the perfect approach to get this done ? "filter dialog" may not be the most appropriate word for this . So any help is appreciated .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding another navigation drawer on the right side would do the trick. However since you are using fragments you'll need a central activity controller that handles all the fragment changes and the side drawers, preferably the main Navigation Drawer activity could be developed to hold such a role, and it should have logic to lock or free the right side drawer appropriately. A quick and dirty way to bind the right drawer to the fragment is to inflate the layout into the drawer and bind its elements in run-time, but that would result with lots of dependencies and having to pass the drawer to the fragment via parameter, hence it should be designed and implemented properly using callbacks and interfaces between the activity and fragments for good performance.

Comment: can you be more detailed ? big help

Comment: Based on the details provided from your question this is the best I could. Probably you could share your project over Github to further understand the details.